# Can R/r in Musig be derived from only seeds and message hashes?

Tags: schnorr-signatures, musig

I am wondering if the first two roundtrips of pre-committing and then revealing R/r in MuSig signing can be moved to the keygen phase and made deterministic. That reduces the amount of messages that need to be exchanged; since keygen is done only once, we want to expand that phase. This would be especially useful for HD wallets: at the expense of making wallet creation more complicated, signing would need fewer interactions.

The [musig paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/068.pdf) on page 10-11, specifies the following (from perspective of signer 1):

### MuSig scheme

**Key generation**

1. generates private key x<sub>1</sub> and corresponding public key X<sub>1</sub>
2. sends X<sub>1</sub>
3. receives X<sub>i</sub>

**Signing (specifically the part about agreeing on R<sub>i</sub>)**

1. sends t<sub>1</sub>=H<sub>com</sub>(R<sub>1</sub>)
2. receives t<sub>i</sub>
3. sends R<sub>1</sub>
4. receives R<sub>i</sub>
5. checks that H<sub>com</sub>(R<sub>i</sub>)==t<sub>i</sub>

r<sub>1</sub> is specified to be random.
Signing includes three rounds of interaction, two of which is used for the above steps (agreeing on R<sub>i</sub>).
I want to move these steps to the keygen phase.

---

A HD wallet would presumably use BIP32 to generate X<sub>1</sub>.
Can we use BIP32 for deriving R<sub>i</sub>/r<sub>i</sub> too?

Consider the following scheme instead.
(from cosigners 1's perspective)

### Proposed HD scheme

**HD wallet setup phase**

1. generates xprv y<sub>1</sub> and corresponding xpub Y<sub>1</sub>
2. generates xprv k<sub>1</sub> and corresponding xpub K<sub>1</sub>
3. sends xpub Y<sub>1</sub>
4. sends u<sub>1</sub>=H(K<sub>1</sub>)
5. receives xpub Y<sub>i</sub>
6. receives u<sub>i</sub>
7. sends xpub K<sub>1</sub>
8. receives xpub K<sub>i</sub>
9. checks that H(K<sub>i</sub>)==u<sub>i</sub>

**Key generation**

1. from xprv y<sub>1</sub> along some BIP32 path p, derive private key x<sub>1</sub> and public key X<sub>1</sub>
2. from xpub Y<sub>i</sub> along same BIP32 path p, derive public key X<sub>i</sub>
3. from xprv K<sub>1</sub> along same BIP32 path p, derive private key j<sub>1</sub> and public key J<sub>1</sub>
4. from xpub K<sub>i</sub> along same BIP32 path p, derive public key J<sub>i</sub>.

**Signing (specifically the part about agreeing on R<sub>i</sub>)**

1. compute r<sub>1</sub>=j<sub>1</sub>+hash(m) and R<sub>1</sub>=J<sub>1</sub>+hash(m)*G
2. compute R<sub>i</sub>=J<sub>i</sub>+hash(m)*G

This approach only has one round of interaction during signing (sending s<sub>i</sub>, omitted as its not changed from what is described in the paper).

I have read the derandomization section, but the explanation for why it doesn't work requires R<sub>i</sub> to be chosen by the attacker. If we make it deterministically derived, and BIP32 is safe, then this attack does not apply. The paper states "each signer must ensure that whenever any R<sub>j</sub> sent by other cosigners or the message m changes, his r<sub>i</sub> value changes unpredictably. As long as f is deterministic, this implies a circular dependency in the choice of random values."

Where is this circular dependency? The f from RFC 6979 only depends on key and m.

Comment: I can't comment about the interaction with Musig, but I'll add my intuition here in a comment.  If by your design, the signature's nonce is chosen by the signer by way of *public* key derivation, and this is disclosed to another party who learns the public derivable path between private key and nonce, then they now have a function of the nonce as the public key.  This most likely will leak the private key when a valid signature over some message is published by the signer.

Comment: The circular dependency only appears when there are multiple parties. In order for a deterministic algorithm to be secure, it must require every party's nonce to depend on every other nonce (because as long as anyone's nonce changes between two runs, yours must also - or you leak your private keys). You can't have k1=F(x1,m,k2*G) and simultaneously k2=F(x2,m,k1*G).

Comment: This circular dependency only appears of the nonce isn't provably deterministic. If everyone would be able to prove to everyone else that their nonce was computed from just their private key, the message, and everyone's public key, there wouldn't be a problem either. The circular dependency is only when one party could choose to use a different algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construction you're suggesting will likely work as long as you don't sign more than one message. By effectively choosing the R points ahead of time, you've constructed a single-show signature.

However, the derivation you're using for the different R values is pointless. It's not enough that you don't reuse R values; you can't use multiple *related* R values either. All the R values you are constructing are related through a single linear equation. That is sufficient for an attacker (who knows about the relation) to derive the private key from seeing two signatures.

Comment: Technically linear relations can be okay so long as there are more unknowns than equations.  E.g. if you agree on a 3000 degree polynomial, you can use messages hashes to pick locations to interpolate, and make up to 2999 signatures.  But critically all of this stuff is SUPER hard to get right and super hard to verify. Most cryptographic constructions are broken.  I would really caution anyone against being too clever with this stuff.